# Any map site which allows me to see a number of addresses in the same map?

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there any map site which allows me to enter a number of addresses and I can see all of their locations on a single map?

I think I can do that in Google Maps, but it requires a lot of steps:

1. enter my address
2. save my address to 'my map'
3. enter address 2
4. save my address 2 to 'my map'
5. go to 'my map' to see both 1 and 2 address

Repeat the above steps again and again.

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Google Docs spreadsheet with the addresses on one sheet, and on another sheet it can automatically display the map showing a pin for each address:
http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=91601

Looks like there's also a more powerful (and complicated!) way that works with both Google Maps and Google Earth:
http://earth.google.com/outreach/tutorial_spreadsheet.html

Answer (score 1):

On Google Maps, the widget in the top-right corner of the map that lets you switch between regular map and satellite view also maintains a list of recently-entered addresses. Hover over that list and check the addresses you want on the map.

[image: Google Maps: Multiple Addresses]

I'm not sure what the limit is -- I stopped trying after I had 10 addresses on the map.

Answer (score 0):

I usually map a route between the addresses. That makes all the pins show up, but you have to ignore the routing lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can also star multiple locations on Google Maps. And you can view those stars on the map. And it will sync to mobile too.